# Prononciation of Suzhou

Tags: pronunciation

What is the pronunciation of the city Suzhou?
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en-7tRfwDRI), it looks like she says "Shu dshjo". [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6oYyVCFCg8) it's more "Shu djo". [Here](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%8B%8F%E5%B7%9E%E5%B8%82) it sounds more like "Su djo".

Comment: IMO, the pronunciation in the first video is entirely wrong, it sounds like "shi jiu" to me. The second two pronunciations are correct, it's just the difference in length of sounds and human versus computer that made the difference of "shu" versus "su".

Comment: Haha well the first video does mention, "[l]earn how to say words in English correctly."

Comment: All of them are wrong

Answer (score 2):

If your language is English, try 'sue joe' both first tone.